# Cannot link third-party library to a js script in Sage theme WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, trellis, roots-sage

I have installed a third-party library called **Moment.js** through `bower install --save moment`. I have a script named ***calendar.js*** placed in scripts folder of my theme. However, when I use moment in my calendar.js it seems the library isn't linked to it. When I move all the code from ***calendar.js*** to ***main.js***, everything works fine. The problem is that I need to pass the data into the script by loading a json file and send the data by AJAX so I need to make a separate script, which, in this case, ***calendar.js***. So how do I solve this problem?

**Edit**: I've enqueued **calendar.js** in my theme's `functions.php` like this:

```
function igs_scripts_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'calendar', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/calendar.js', array(), false, true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'igs_scripts_styles');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register and enqueue script before using it in wordpress then only wordpress will be able to recognise the script. As of what i can understand the main.js and Moment.js scripts are added properly using wp_enqueue_script which is why they are working fine. I believe if you enqueue the Calendar.js as well that JS file will work fine too.

Comment: I did enqueue the calendar.js, main.js is enqueued in wordpress default setup. Moment.js is installed through bower --save so it should be automatically available:
https://roots.io/sage/docs/theme-development-and-building/

Comment: can you share your enqueue code because as of what i understand from what you said your calendar.js file is not enqueued properly.

Comment: If your Calendar.js file have jquery that you need to add dependency by adding 'jquery' inside array.

Comment: Please visit: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/ to learn more about enqueue script. You will get the answer there.

Comment: I use jQuery in calendar.js without a trouble

Comment: hey can I ask you a question? How do I control the order of inclusion of assets? I want some libraries to be included after moment.js

Answer (score -1):

It's not really a solution to this problem but a workaround. So I noticed when I moved all the code from **calendar.js** to **main.js** it worked all fine. What I did is enqueuing **calendar.js** with the dependency of **main.js** (because moment.js is available in **main.js**). Here's the code:

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'calendar', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/scripts/calendar.js', ['sage/js'], null, true );
```